# How do I define and print evaluation committee members in the coverpage

Tags: formatting, memoir

I'm writing the coverpage for my thesis in the `memoir` class and I've been trying to define the command to print the evaluation committee. I'm trying something like

`\newcommand{\committeemember}[4]{\committeemember{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}`

where I would input the member position in the committee (chair, rapporteur, member), name, job and affiliation, but I'm not sure how to iterate over all the inputed committee members and print them out in a tabular setting like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: Alternatively, since there are only four members and one title page, why not do a `tabular` by hand, since that would be quicker? Programmable solution(s) depend greatly on datamodel structures and desired methodologies. For example, it could be done with `biblatex` with a custom cite command and bibentries containing `xsv` fields. It could be done other ways as well.